# Data Conversion & date/time wildcards

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract, tracking-extract

I have a data conversion step in an automation that follows this file naming convention:

`MemberCommunication_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%%%Hour%%0000.csv`

I needed the timestamp to facilitate the ETL process but couldn't use the minute/second wildcards in that ETL process for whatever reason (some limitation on the changing file name).

But, I had to do some catch-up extracts so to avoid overwriting the files on the FTP, I added in the minute wildcard so the file name would be: `MemberCommunication_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%%%Hour%%%%Minute%%00.csv` but that kept causing an error.  I added in `%%Second%%` too and that didn't work either.

Once I changed back to `MemberCommunication_%%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%%%Hour%%0000.csv` the automation completed fine.

Does the data convert step not support all wildcards?  I saw an older thread that implied such but that makes no sense.

Comment: a) Where are you getting the error? and b) what is the code that you have written causing the error?

Comment: Do you mean a Data Extract step? We're currently using the following in a data extract with no issue %%Year%%%%Month%%%%Day%%-%%Hour%%%%Minute%%.csv

Comment: yes, @MCQs, it's the data conversion step of a data extract.  The extract step using the wildcards completes successfully, but the data conversion step does not so long as I'm using %%Minute%% and %%Second%% in the file name.